# Why $ guesses the column names when used for data frame?

Tags: r

I incidentally found a surprising behavior for `$` operator when selecting columns in data frames:

```
gg <- data.frame(faa = 1:10, gaa = rep(c("x", "y"), 5))  

gg$f
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I always thought that you have to use exact column name for `$` too, maybe because that is how it works for `"["`. It seems that `$` operator guesses the rest of the column name because there are no other columns starting with f.

```
ggg <- data.frame(faa = 1:10, gaa = rep(c("x", "y"), 5), faagaa = 1:10)
ggg$f
# NULL
ggg$faag
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

1. Has this behavior been part of R functionality for a long time (because I have not experienced it before) or is it something relatively new?
2. How does it work? I.e. what is the mechanism behind this behavior?
3. How could one use this as an advantage when working with R? (other cases where $ works in a similar way)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153904/partial-matching-of-function-argument  :)

Comment: Ah, OK. It was answered already. I tried searhing "partial matching data frame", but did not try "function". Thanks!